# using indexes in the right way for python insert method

Tags: python, insert

I have a bit of a problem understanding what is going on inside of an insert method in python. I have been trying to manually insert elements into an empty array, some of them are working just fine but the other ones (index 2 and index 3) ara swapped. So here in this picture I believe 'q' should be in the index of 2 and 'd' in the index of '3' but it is the other way around. I understand that when I assign 'd' on index 3, there is not enough elements in blist array to insert on 3rd index.

```
blist = []
blist.insert(1, "h")
blist.insert(3, "d")
blist.insert(2, "q")
blist.insert(0, "g")
blist.insert(4, "k")
```

```
intended output: ['g', 'h', 'q', 'd', 'k']

output: ['g', 'h', 'd', 'q', 'k']
```

if someone could help me understand what I might be doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the list at each step?  Hint: after you say `blist.insert(1, "h")`, `"h"` is *not* at index 1!

Comment: Precisely what @Samwise said. Because the index 1 does not exist at that point. Python uses zero-based indexes in lists

Comment: For what you're trying to accomplish, you'd be better off creating a list of tuples and then `sort`ing it.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: If you wish to insert elements in specific indexes you need to make sure those indexes exist. One option would be to create a list with `None` at each position, and then inserting the elements afterwards. Or even replacing the elements

Comment: @MatBBastos thank you so much for the idea, that actually helped!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the index you are inserting in is higher than the length of the list, the string will be inserted at the end of the list.
That means if you run:

```
blist = []
blist.insert(1, "h")
blist.insert(3, "d")
```

the list will look like this:

```
["h","d"]
```

if you now run: `blist.insert(2, "q")` it will put q at index 2 (the end of the list)

Answer (score 0):

The code is working completely fine.

Below is the explanation of what is happening at each step.

```
At this point there is one element in the list.
    blist.insert(1, "h")
    ['h']
The index of h -> 0

    blist.insert(3, "d")
    ['h', 'd']
At this point d is inserted at index 3 but as there is only one element in the list its index in the list is d -> 1

    blist.insert(2, "q")
    ['h', 'd', 'q']
A similar thing happens for 2 as well, it is inserted at index 2 and its index in the list becomes q -> 2

Same thing is happening on further insertions
    blist.insert(0, "g")
    ['g', 'h', 'd', 'q']

    blist.insert(4, "k")
    ['g', 'h', 'd', 'q', 'k']
```

Comment: thank you so much, it makes a lot more sense now!!

Comment: I had to do a problem where I was given index 1 first, then index3, then 2 and 0. Can you suggest any solution what I can do to keep the array in order? Can you think of a different method that can be used to keep the order as intended? I hope I made the question clear

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Save these values in a dictionary as key (index), value (element) pairs. and then create a list according to the correct key (index) values.

Comment: wonderful, thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

If you specifically want an array. Arrays need to first be imported, or declared, from other libraries (i.e. numpy).

if the index at which you want to insert the item does not exist it will be inserted at another position.

i recommend running code in this environment, so you can see what happens at each step, and where the items get inserted:
http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

A list of the different list methods can be found:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp